# Javascript dynamic textbox change focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onfocus

I have a HTML form with some static text box and a button that will create dynamic text boxes. Now when the button is clicked I want the new created box to be focused. I am using `focus()` method but it is not working. Another thing is I have a `onFocus()` method that will change the background color which is working in static boxes but not in the dynamic boxes.

```
function addPhone(){
try{
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    phone.appendChild(document.createElement("Phone"+noOfPhones));

    var textbox = document.createElement("input");
    textbox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
    textbox.setAttribute("id","phone"+noOfPhones);
    textbox.setAttribute("name","phone"+noOfPhones);

    textbox.setAttributte('onFocus','onFocus(this);');
    textbox.style.background="lightgrey";

    document.getElementById("phone").appendChild(textbox);
    phone.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    textbox.focus();

    noOfPhones++;
}catch(err){
    alert(err);
}

}

function onFocus(element){
element.style.background = "lightgrey";
}
```

Please help. I am new to JS.

Comment: Yuck, what is that `try catch` for? I hope that's not staying in your code.

Comment: @JuanMendes Definitely not. I am new to JS so trying to catch the errors.

Comment: Your error will show up in the console, there's no need for the try catch

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div id="phone"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="addPhone()" value="Add"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var noOfPhones=0;
function addPhone(){
    try{
        noOfPhones++;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
        phone.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Phone :"+noOfPhones));
        var textbox = document.createElement("input");
        textbox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
        textbox.setAttribute("id","phone"+noOfPhones);
        textbox.setAttribute("name","phone"+noOfPhones);
        textbox.setAttribute('onfocus','onFocus(this, true);');
        textbox.setAttribute('onblur','onFocus(this, false);');
        textbox.style.background="white";
        document.getElementById("phone").appendChild(textbox);
        phone.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        textbox.focus();
    }catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
}

function onFocus(element, hasFocus){
if(hasFocus)
    element.style.background = "lightgrey";
else
    element.style.background = "white";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have solved it in rather very unusual way. If I put the function addPhone() in the html file it works but if I move this to an external main.js file, it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont know why this has happened, but I the code works fine (with all the scripts in external file) in firefox. So I cleared the cache in Chrome and it is now working in Chrome also.